Do WSL & Windows share audio devices?
I'm currently developing a transcription application in WSL using Ubuntu and the PortAudio library. I am curious if WSL and Windows share audio devices? At the moment the PortAudio library is not detecting any audio devices at all on the system, which I can only assume means the answer to my question is no. If this is the case, I am reaching out for any help or information on how to setup my audio device to work on my subsystem.
I am trying to avoid having to rebuild my environment and libraries onto my windows system if I can since everything is already on WSL.
My current version of PortAudio is portaudio19-dev and my PyAudio is 0.2.14. My ubuntu is 22.04
